# Bigquery : convert class to Bigquery TableSchema

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Do you know a way to convert a Java Class (which has been generated through jaxb from xsd and so contains XML bind annotation) to a Bigquery TableSchema.

Or alternatively convert a JsonScheam to TableSchema.

I have to do so for about 60 more or less complex class.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Consider using reflection on your class to get a list of fields on the class and use it to generate the TableSchema.
https://www.journaldev.com/1789/java-reflection-example-tutorial#all-public-fields

Alternatively you can use this [JavaClassParser](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/classfile/ClassParser.html), but reflection may be simpler.

Comment: I Alex, this is what I currently do... Ok so no official thing. Thanks for comment